# How to solve the error when using prompt() in Javascript when using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to prompt a user with a message to enter a value and then store that entered value into a variable named 'a'. I want to do this in Visual Studio Code, NOT in the browser. I am using JavaScript as a programming language.

I have already installed node.js JavaScript runtime environment in my PC.

I entered this code in Visual Studio Code:`let a = prompt("Enter the value:");`

But I got the following error:

*[Running] node "c:\Users\joshisu\OneDrive - LHSC & St. Joseph's\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.js"
c:\Users\joshisu\OneDrive - LHSC & St. Joseph's\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:1
let a = prompt("enter the value:", a)
^
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
at Object. (c:\Users\joshisu\OneDrive - LHSC & St. Joseph's\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:1:9)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
Node.js v20.11.0
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.236 seconds*

After that, I opened the Terminal in Visual Studio Code (View --> Terminal) and ran this command, which as per my understanding will install the prompt-sync Node.js package in my project. `npm install prompt-sync`
I got the message that it added 3 packages.

Then, in my project (in my test.js file), I tried to use the prompt-sync module by requiring it in the beginning of my code: `const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();`

And then tried again to use the prompt, so that the user can enter the value and it gets stored in the variable a:
`let a = prompt("Enter the value:");`

But again, I got the following error:
*[Running] node "c:\Users\joshisu\OneDrive - LHSC & St. Joseph's\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.js"
c:\Users\joshisu\OneDrive - LHSC & St. Joseph's\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:1
let a = prompt("Enter the value:");
^
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
at Object. (c:\Users\joshisu\OneDrive - LHSC & St. Joseph's\Desktop\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:1:9)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
Node.js v20.11.0
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.432 seconds*

Is it possible to prompt a user to enter the value and store it in the variable 'a', and I want everything to be done in Visual Studio Code, NOT in web browser.

Thank you.